# Animated swap position of two buttons

Tags: android, animation, button, swap

I am trying to swap the position of two buttons.
My swapping code looks is:

```
private void exchangeButtons(Button btn1, Button btn2) {
    // Create the animation set
    AnimationSet exchangeAnimation = new AnimationSet(true);
    TranslateAnimation translate = new TranslateAnimation(
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, btn2.getLeft(),
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, btn1.getLeft(),
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, btn2.getRight(),
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, btn1.getRight());
    translate.setDuration(500);
    exchangeAnimation.addAnimation(translate);
    //int fromX = btn1.getLeft();
    //int fromY = btn1.getRight();
    //int toX = btn2.getLeft();
    //int toY = btn2.getRight();
    Log.d("ArrangeMe", 
        "view1 pos:" + btn1.getLeft() + ", 
        " +btn1.getRight() + "view2 pos:" + 
        btn2.getLeft() + ", " + btn2.getRight());
    AnimationSet exchangeAnimation1 = new AnimationSet(true);
    TranslateAnimation translate1 = new TranslateAnimation( 
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, btn1.getLeft(),
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, btn2.getLeft(),
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, btn1.getRight(),
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, btn2.getRight());
    translate1.setDuration(500);
    exchangeAnimation1.addAnimation(translate1);
    // EXECUTE btn1.startAnimation(exchangeAnimation);
    btn2.startAnimation(exchangeAnimation1);
}
```

I call the code as below:

```
exchangeButtons(button1, button2);
```

My layout looks as below:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button 
        android:text="One" 
        android:id="@+id/button1" 
        android:layout_height="70px" 
        android:layout_width="70px" 
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </Button>
    <Button 
        android:text="Two" 
        android:id="@+id/button2" 
        android:layout_height="70px" 
        android:layout_width="70px" 
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

What happens when I execute the code is:

Instead of the buttons exchanging their positions, they just disappear for sometime[may be 500 ms] and reappear as they were originally.

How to resolve this problem ? Will it work properly in device ?

Answer (score 3):

You wont get the getRight value in onCreate because the UI hasn't been drawn on the screen so none of the UI elements are measure yet. Try this

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = btn1.getViewTreeObserver();  
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {  
    @Override  
    public void onGlobalLayout() {  
        btn1.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);  
        int left = btn1.getLeft(); 
    }  
});
```

Put the code in the onCreate method

Answer (score 1):

Android's  `TranslateAnimation` doesn't reposition your components, it just animates the transition you want to do - after that, it's up to you to change the layout params of your component (take a look at this [post](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg49872.html)).

P.S. You can use directly the translate animation, without using a whole new animation set. Another good thing will be to create the animations when your layout is inflated and to override `onSizeChanged(int, int, int, int)` to re-create them using the new dimensions.

What's the layout you are using?

Answer (score 0):

```
 b4.setOnClickListener {
        try {


            var arswap = arrayListOf<Button>(b1, b2, b3);
            var randomPos: Int = 0;


            fun swap(b1: Button, b2: Button) {
                var tempPosition = Point(b1.x.toInt(), b1.y.toInt())
                b1.x = b2.x;
                b1.y = b2.y;

                b2.x = tempPosition.x.toFloat();
                b2.y = tempPosition.y.toFloat();
            }

            var totalItems: Int = 3; // total number of items

            for (i in 0..totalItems/3 ) {

                randomPos = ((Math.random() * arswap.size).toInt());
                var randomItem =  ((Math.random() * ((totalItems / 2) - 1)) + ((totalItems / 2) + 1));


                swap(arswap[randomPos], arswap[randomItem.toInt()])
            }
        }catch (e:Exception){

        }

    }
```