# How to swap positions of 2 views via animation in android?

Tags: android, android-animation

As my question says, I need to swap positions of 2 views present on my Activity. My Activity contains a RelativeLayout, which has 2 views which are positioned at different locations, depending upon certain conditions.

The 2 Views that I need to swap are RelativeLayouts, lets call them as Layout1 and Layout2.
So, when these are visible on screen, and user presses a button present at a fixed location in top-right corner, I need to swap the positions of these 2 layouts.

Earlier, I had achieved this, but those layouts were having fixed height then and were positioned one below the other. So all I had to do was vertical movement.
But now, dimensions as well as positioning has been made dynamic and hence that code does not work.

So could someone please help me out here?

[Just to give an idea about what I have tried --I tried getting the views positions on screen using getLocationOnScreen() and the subtracting the X and Y values to get the idea of how much X/Y movement needs to be done. This doesn't work as expected and sometimes moves layouts to opposite directions when they are overlapping.

Are there any other ways someone could suggest to achieve this animation?

Another problem I had with getLocationOnScreen() is that it strangely gives me same location for both the layouts for the first time..and after one animation, starts giving me the correct values]

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686846/animated-swap-position-of-two-buttons?lq=1